# Determining best start and end points for line segment on polygon

Tags: java, algorithm, math, geometry, jts

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to solve the following problem. I've tried out multiple methods of solving them but I'm always running into some corner cases.

The problem is the following:

1. You have a `List` of coordinates (x and y points) forming a closed polygon. This list is guaranteed to form a polygon with points ordered in a clockwise direction.
2. You are given a `Set` of coordinates (x and y points) which are from the above `List` of coordinates.
3. You must figure out the start and end points of the line formed using all points in the above `Set`.

The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out the method of finding the 'best' start and end points. For many scenarios, you can pick the first and last point (using the indices of the `List`) to form the start and end points, however this could result in a line which is longer than it has to be.

For example, let's say we have the following polygon:
`0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 0`
And the following `Set` of coordinates our line segment must contain: `0, 7, 3`.

If we find the min and max indices, we get `index(0)`, `index(7)`, so we can form the line `0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7`, which is a valid line but it is longer than it needs to be. The best line segment would be `7 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3`.

How can I find the best (shortest which contains all points in `Set`) line segment in an efficient manner?

For context: I'm working on an application which using JTS Geometries to draw shapes. The drawn shapes are smoothed using Bezier curves to result in 'curved edges'. After drawing the shapes (by dropping points), users can edit the shape. We want to figure out the start and end points using the points they modify (forms the `Set` above) so we can 'smooth' only the affected area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your set into sorted list, concatenate this list with it's copy, where every element is added with number of polygon vertices N, then find the longest empty run (neighbor difference) in this doubled list. Then get sublist of needed length, transform it to continuous range (but take elements modulo N)

```
(0,3,7) + (0+8,3+8,7+8) = (0,3,7,8,11,15)
```

max difference is  7-3, so the best case sublist starts with 7, it is

```
 (7%8 .. 11%8) = (7,0,1,2,3)
```

Comment: The numbers in the lists correspond to the indices of the points right?

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. That seems to work great. If you don't mind, can you explain the 'math' behind this approach? Why does it work?

Comment: You need to properly treat **cyclic** sequence with possible transition over zero.Simple way - to double data set.

Comment: Great, thank you. I have combined your answer with Jacob's to make my code, seems to work great. For my particular use case, I just care about the start and end points so simply using a sorted set and also comparing first and last seems more efficient rather than concatenating the list, which would be better if we wanted all the points (I realize I worded my question poorly).

Answer (score 1):

so we have a `Set` and we nead to walk this set in the order of the index into `List`.

convert `ISet` = `[Index(i, List) for i in Set]`

next sort `ISet`

for pairs of consecutive items in `ISet` and the pair (last, first) compute the distances for that pair.

fined the pair with the max distances. Then the best end and start are that pair.

Comment: By distances, do you mean the difference between the two pairs?

Comment: Great, thank you. I used MBo's answer above to make my code but used your simple trick of just comparing (last, first) to eliminate the need to copy the set.